# My App shows popup recommending some App for which I did not write any code

Tags: android

While testing my app suddenly I got a popup saying

> MyApp_Name recommends News Dog

I was surprised as I didn't include any code for showing any kinds of advertisements. Why is this happening? Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Comment: "Why is this happening?" -- presumably, you are including some third-party library that is doing this.

Comment: I have only included **ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar**

Comment: @CommonsWare : How do I pinpoint the exact reason behind this.

Comment: Eliminate dependencies, one at a time, until you find whichever one is doing this.

Comment: @CommonsWare : I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: I think, it's not due to your code, some other app is prompting that popup. Review your all app-list carefully.

Comment: I noticed that the issue is only occuring on a specific device. I tested my app on 5 devices. Out of the 5, the issue is encountered only on 1 device. I searched about the issue and came across [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/BsHrjAFOLTw) and [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63140/find-what-app-is-causing-popups-not-in-notification-bar). I think there is no problem with the third-party libraries that I am using. I guess there is some adware on that particular device which is causing the issue. Need to research more.